# Can only use some commands as sudo

Tags: bash, terminal, path, sudo

I have had a bit of a problem with some commands lately, not working as intended.
I wanted to fiddle with some Markdown and try it as a substitute for some simple HTML pages, so I looked into some easy to use tools and found pandoc.

I went ahead, installed it, it was succesfull and I opened Terminal.app.
However, I am not able to run my command as **normal user**:

`-bash: pandoc: command not found`

If I do a `man pandoc` I am able to see the manual, so I know it is installed.

But I am able to run it as super user aka root.

If I try `sudo pandoc` I am able to use the tool,
for example `sudo pandoc -s test.mdown -o test.html`

What is the reason for this and is it easy to fix? It is working perfectly fine on my laptop, but not on my desktop computer.

My $PATH is
`/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/texbin`

Thanks in advance, this really grinds my gear.

Comment: what does sudo which pandoc say?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/pandoc`

Comment: What are the permissions and ownership of `pandoc`?

Comment: As I understand you, you are able to run the command as `root` user (using the command `sudo pandoc`), but not as normal user. What does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/pandoc` say? Maybe only root has permissions to execute the file? And what happens if you start it as `/usr/local/bin/pandoc` (with the full path)?

Comment: `ls: /usr/local/bin/pandoc: Permission denied` so it looks like permission problems. If I try to run with full path I get `-bash: /usr/local/bin/pandoc: Permission denied`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have `+x` for `/usr/local/bin`. You would get a `Permission denied` error if this were a problem with the executable itself; as is, it appears to be a problem with the directory.

Comment: How do I do this? Just `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin`? EDIT: Looks like it's working now, thanks. Any reason why my permission was changed, I do not recall changing anything?

Comment: You can check this by running `ls -l /usr/local`. Assuming `root` owns that directory, you would have to do `sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

pandoc probably can't be found in the PATH for the root user. If you can log in as root, run

`env | grep ^PATH`